# Django-cms with custom user model: LookupError: Model 'accounts.CustomUser' not registered

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-cms

Using Django 3.2/Django-cms 3.11.

I am encountering an issue when trying to add `PlaceholderField` from `cms.models.fields` in my `events.models` module to the `EventVenue` model.

```
from cms.models.fields import PlaceholderField
class EventVenue(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=255)
    slider = PlaceholderField('room_slider')
```

the settings:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'modeltranslation',
    'djangocms_admin_style',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.forms',
    
    'haystack',
    'accounts',
    'cms',
    'menus',
    'treebeard',
    'sekizai',
    'filer',
    'easy_thumbnails',
    'mptt',
    'simple_history',
    'crispy_forms',
    'crispy_bootstrap5',

    'djangocms_text_ckeditor',
    'djangocms_link',
    'djangocms_file',
    'djangocms_picture',
    'djangocms_video',
    'djangocms_googlemap',
    'djangocms_snippet',
    'djangocms_style',
    'djangocms_forms',
    'django_flatpickr',
    'phonenumber_field',

    'bgv_cms',
    'ddz_cms',
    'events',
    'mail_list',
]
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.CustomUser'
```

the custom user class:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,blank=True, null=True, related_name='employee')
    mailing_list = models.ManyToManyField(to='MailList', related_name='mail_list', blank=True, verbose_name=_('Mailing lists'))
    room = models.CharField(_('Room Mailing Lists'), max_length=100, choices=FLOOR, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ('username',)

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.get_full_name() or self.username
```

Here's the relevant part of the traceback:

```
from events.models import EventVenue
  File "C:\Users\SAIF\Desktop\projects\bgv\bgv\events\models.py", line 17, in <module>
    from cms.models.fields import PlaceholderField
  File "C:\Users\SAIF\Anaconda3\envs\bgv\lib\site-packages\cms\models\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .permissionmodels import *  # nopyflakes
  File "C:\Users\SAIF\Anaconda3\envs\bgv\lib\site-packages\cms\models\permissionmodels.py", line 19, in <module>
    User = apps.get_registered_model(user_app_name, user_model_name)
  File "C:\Users\SAIF\Anaconda3\envs\bgv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 273, in get_registered_model
    raise LookupError(
LookupError: Model 'accounts.CustomUser' not registered.
```

i have tried to change the app order in the INSTALLED_APPS and inherit from the `PermissionsMixin` in the custom user but didn't work

the Organization class in the accounts app:

```
class Organization(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    contact_person = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, 
                                       on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                       blank=True, null=True, 
                                       help_text=_('if you changed the contact person to another user, you lose access to this organization info.'),
                                       related_name='owner')
responsible_for_room = models.ForeignKey(EventVenue, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,blank=True, null=True, related_name='responsible_for_room')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: To clarify: if you remove the Placeholderfield, everything runs normal?!

Comment: @benzkji Yes, if i remove the Placeholderfield all works fine

Comment: what was it, in the end?

Comment: `responsible_for_room`, I guess?

Comment: i removed the import of the `EventVenue ` and change it like this and it worked:
 ```responsible_for_room = models.ForeignKey('events.EventVenue', on_delete=models.SET_NULL,blank=True, null=True, related_name='responsible_for_room')```

Comment: in general a good idea, to reference other models in foreign keys and m2m fields like this - it also helps avoiding circular imports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a few tests with adding `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in my current project, my conclusions are the following:

- using `AUTH_USER_MODEL` with the django-cms requires attention to detail
- changing `INSTALLED_APPS` orders could help, but not for me (and not the OP)
- what helped for me, was making sure, that my app that contains the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` imports nothing at all cms related (i.e. no PageField, no models, no helpers or anything. Can't list all of it, but you'll get it). Because this will trigger loading of the permissionsmodel, which wants to import the user model. Also, any app (in `INSTALLED_APPS`) before the one containing your user should consequently not import anything cms.

So for this specific case/question, it would mean checking the `accounts` app for any cms imports. And also, for any other imports that could trigger cms imports, as for example the `Organization`  - this could be removed, and the foreign key be noted as `models.ForeignKey("organization_app.Organization",....)`  - as I don't know where `Organization` lives.

This is not fully researched, but could help anyway. Fun fact: If you specify `AUTH_USER_MODEL = "auth.User"` everything runs ok.

Comment: i am not directly importing any cms components to the `accounts` app.
i have the organization class in the accounts app with the user model(i will included it in the post)
so you said if i change the `Organization` model to other app it might works??

Comment: everything a bit vague, hard to say. a few more lines of the traceback would be helpful as well.

Comment: if `Organization` has a PlaceholderField, I would say extracting it could help. But it doesn't seem so..

Comment: it may be that `FLOOR` is imported from the events app? ...speculations. My generic guess ist, that something loads the events model, before cms is loaded.